# Error when invoking lambda from StepFunction with paypload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, payload, aws-step-functions

I have a lambda and it's one of the steps of a StepFunction statemachine, the lambda handler looks like this below :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    year = event['year'] #payload
    month = event['month'] #payload
    example_function(year, month)
```

This lambda execution succeeded if f I start a run in Lambda itself with payload:

```
{
  "year": "2019",
  "month": "06"
}
```

However if I kick off a stepfunction run, it will fail with error:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'year'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/xxx.py", line 34, in lambda_handler
    year = event['year']
```

My stepfunction definition is:

```
{
    "Comment": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "StartAt": "invoke lambda",
    "States": {
      "invoke lambda" : {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
        "Parameters": {
          "FunctionName":"xxxxxxxxxx",
          "Payload": {
            "Input": {
              "year": "2019",
              "month": "06"
            }
          }
        }
        "End": true
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure how to debug and solve this issue, might someone be able to help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to call the lambda function from step function.

First Method, directly by giving the Resource name as lambda Arn and passing the entire input to Parameters. This passes given input as is to Lambda

```
{
   "StartAt":"invoke-lambda",
   "States":{
      "invoke-lambda":{
         "End":true,
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:660008888333:function:HelloWorld",
         "Parameters":{
            "year":"2019",
            "month":"06"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Second Method using Resource `lambda:invoke` and Payload with Json body(no need to wrap within Input)

```
{
   "StartAt":"invoke-lambda",
   "States":{
      "invoke-lambda":{
         "End":true,
         "Type":"Task",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
         "Parameters":{
            "FunctionName":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:660008888333:function:HelloWorld",
            "Payload":{
               "year":"2019",
               "month":"06"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If input to Lambda is from either previous step or from input to step function input, we can use `"Payload.$": "$"` or even `"Payload.$": "$.subPath"`(to pass part of json)
Also it is recommended to add a Retry for exceptions that are triggered because of Exceptions caused by AWS.

```
{
  "StartAt": "invoke-lambda",
  "States": {
    "invoke-lambda": {
      "End": true,
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:660008888333:function:HelloWorld",
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "InvocationType": "RequestResponse"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, Can I ask a follow-up question, in this way the payload will be hard-coded in the stepfunction definition file, but it's not ideal in production, how we can address this issue? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: we can use either,  i have added another example for passing input and retry

Comment: Hi just wanted to add a quick update, the first approach won't work when there is other steps in the stepfunction after this lambda, because there is nothing in the output path so the task after this lambda don't have input messages.

Comment: ok. in general, output of a task will simply be passed to next step and input will be removed, if we don't specify resultPath and/or outputPath. Example , we can add  `"OutputPath":"$","ResultPath":"$.myOut"` which will append output to myOut.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830196/step-functions-use-output-from-older-step-in-later-step-non-sequential/65831062#65831062) is an example