What is the Typescript type of a AWS Lambda event coming from a Step Function
@types/aws-lambda lists the Event type for 34 different sources, from ALB to SQS, but SFN or StepFunctions is not on the list.
I just want to be able to (confidently) write
export const hander:Handler<SFNEvent> = (event) => {

Anybody know where this is?

Such type doesn't exist: SFN does not modify or wrap the payload, your lambda will receive whatever your machine passed as input.

@STerliakov And nothing else?  Not the calling step-function?  The user?  Nothing?

You also have the context object passed as 2nd argument, but the event is exactly the same as passed by SFN. Here's a QA with an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54358287/pass-and-use-input-parameters-to-a-lambda-task-from-a-step-function

@STerliakov — if you would like, you can promote your response to an answer and I’ll accept it and you’ll get all the fake Internet points.  Otherwise, I’ll do it.

Step Functions does not impose any restrictions on the type of the “event”, which Step Functions calls the “payload”, except I suppose that it must be expressible in JSON.  Consider the following state-machine:
{
  "StartAt": "InvokeVendor",
  "States": {
    "InvokeVendor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ResultPath": "$.vendorResult",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke-vendor",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:011668294191:function:vendor-webhook",
        "Payload": {
          "path": "process-webhook"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The handler for this could be written as:
export const handler: Handler<{ path: string }> = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const route = routes[event.path];
  if (!route) {
    throw new Error(`Path ${event.path} not understood`);
  }
  return route(event, context, callback);
};

(Note the pattern used here, of passing in a path and then using that to dispatch to a function that does the actual work, is by no means necessary, but is a handy way to reduce the number of separate Lambdas a complex project will require.)
Thanks to @STerliakov for explaining this to me.
